# C# Windows Form :Strict some fields according to the logged in user

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on Windows Form (C#) visual studio and .net 3.5,
my program is a database-based, with multi-user, 
database store info about devices and contract, 

what I need is a way to restrict specific fields to (Modify,ReadOnly,Hidden) 
receptively to the logged-in user privileges, 
I don't want to use windows users, I want my users (from a database)to make them separate from OS,
 at least for now, 
so for example I have a form with 21 fields, 
five of them must be hidden when employee with no financial privileges has logged-in,
but when his supervisor is the user, then he can see the financial field but not modify it's value, 
and when the administrator is logged-in he can do what every he wants to do

I hope I make it clear enough to help me out,

Answer (score 0):

If you've read the user and their privileges from your database, it's just a matter of setting the `Visible` property of any control you don't want shown.

```
this.FinanceField1.Visible = !IsEmployee();
this.FinanceField2.Visible = !IsEmployee();

this.FinanceField3.Enabled = !IsSupervisor();
```

Or something similar to this.

Comment: Or perhaps `Enabled`, if you want it to be visible but not editable

Comment: as I comment at Drakinfar, I want a more persistent solution, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Implement a permissions table in your database that you read when the use logs in. Then set your form state based upon the passed permission.

Comment: first of all thank you for your response,
I have that in mind, but I need a better solution that is independent from form or visual ... in another word, I a have reports and queries for the same field (SalesPrice appear on the device form and on the report form and on the finance form) I was looking for something like ErrorProvider, I make the restriction once and it will be apply whenever I access that field